# Twig, parser, String only (ban expressions)

Tags: symfony, twig

I am writing a twig tag and i would like to tell the Tokenizer that the tag first Argument is a constant and not an expression.

For the example, lets say my tag is an alias of "echo" :

```
{% tagname 'toto' %}
```

Should yield "toto" (no quotes)

```
{% tagname toto %}
```

Should also yield "toto" (no quotes)

```
{% tagname toto.xx %}
```

Should yield "toto.xx" (no quotes)

The issue is in the last example, the Token parser considers "toto" as an expression and therefore look for a variable named "toto".

So i am wondering if it is possible to specify somehow that the tag argument has to be a constant ?

How my code looks like right now :

```
public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
{
    $parser = $this->parser;
    $stream = $parser->getStream();
    $text = $parser->getExpressionParser()->parseStringExpression();
```

I also tried parsePrimaryExpression, parseHashExpression from the ExpressionParser (is that the error ?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by constant? A PHP constant?

Comment: is there a particular reason you want twig to parse an expression a string... this doesn't really make sense to me. the block tag uses something similar , maybe you should look into that one.

Comment: I understand that it looks strange: Right now, we got a DSL that use a lot of preg_*. I am trying to convert that with twig for maintainability purposes. That DSL is used by end users and i didn't wanted to bother them with "This is not a valid syntax for a string" and be more permissive than twig. But if that's not possible, i may keep the old thing with regular expressions :(.

Comment: @Wouter J, by constant i mean something that will not be evaluated like a string.

Comment: *"A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools."* -Douglas Adams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use both `{% sometag 'foo' %}` and `{% sometag foo %}`?

That's done in the lexer, `SometagTokenParser`. The one with a quote is called `Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE` and the one without quotes is `Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE`. Use something like this in your token parser:

```php
if ($stream->test(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE)) {  
    $name = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE)->getValue();  
} else {  
    $name = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue();  
}
```

Both are just handled as strings in the rest of the application.

Supporting `tuto.foo` without quotes isn't possible in Twig.

Comment: Ok, but if the "argument" is "toto.xx" then, i only get "toto" with one call to "expect" as toto and xx are two tokens. It seems like i cannot loop throught the tokens as the third token is the second argument (toto.xx argument2). Do you see a solution to that ? i feel like i will end up without twig

Comment: `"toto.xx"` is one token (STRING_TYPE), `toto.xx` are 2 tokens

Comment: The issue is i may have arguments like URLs and still in the perspective of using that DSL for an end user, i cannot ask them to put quotes around it. Thank you for your time thought :)

Comment: you can loop throught each tokens until you find a `BLOCK_END_TYPE` or EOF if you want to parse every token and then transform them properly to strings.